# String typeof double in R

Tags: r

Why is my string of type double in R. I am new to R and very confused. How do I convert my variable into a string or character.

```
Browse[1]> x
[1] "2005-04-08"
Browse[1]> is.character(x)
[1] FALSE
Browse[1]> typeof(x)
[1] "double"
Browse[1]> is.String(x)
[1] FALSE
```

This is very confusing as I am trying to write this function:

```
function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) { return(0)}
  if (is.numeric(x)) { return(x) }
  if (is.character(x)) {
    jj = strsplit(x, "-")[[1]]
    if (length(jj) > 1) { return(as.numeric(jj[1])) }
  }
}
```

When `x = NA` first condition is passed. When `x = 2017 or 2000 or some integer year`, the second condition is passed. When `x = "2005-04-08"`, I just want the year portion of it and convert it into an integer.

Comment: What does `str(x)` return?

Comment: @drmariod `Browse[1]> str(x)
 Date[1:1], format: "2005-04-08"`

Comment: @NealBarsch I can't be converting the variable to a character as it is part of my function

Comment: So, this is the answer. It is a numeric value but formatted as date. Use `as.numeric` to get the numeric value. Like `Sys.Date(); is.double(Sys.Date()); as.numeric(Sys.Date())`

Comment: @drmariod I updated my question. I can't be converting the value x to any value I want or else my function logic wont work =[

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why wouldn't you just do an if is.double and then convert x if it is double and not otherwise?

Comment: But it isn't just a character string. It is a date which get's represented as a character string.

Comment: @drmariod, yes true, but what I was saying is use an if for is.double, then your solution.

Comment: maybe `lubridate::is.Date(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You can't double use a variable, which was the issue with my previous answer. It's a little late over here :)

```
fun <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) { return(0)}
  if (is.numeric(x)) { return(x) }
  if (is.character(x)) {
    jj = strsplit(x, "-")[[1]]
    if (length(jj) > 1) { return(as.numeric(jj[1])) }
  }
  if(is.double(x)){
    y <- as.character(x)
    return(as.integer(substr(y ,1,4)))}
}
```

Tested.

```
sys <- Sys.Date()
yyy <- fun(sys)
yyy
[1] 2018
is.double(yyy)
[1] FALSE
is.integer(yyy)
[1] TRUE
```